# Geodesic buffers for polygons in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, buffer

How can I create geodesic buffers around polygons? I'm on 9.3.1 ArcMap, but I need a programatic solution.

IBUfferConstruction only does geodesic buffers for points.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If upgrading to ArcGIS 10.1 (which was recently released) is an option, then this that I just read in the "What's New in ArcGIS 10.1" PDF may be of interest.

> **Geodesic buffering**
>
> The Buffer tool now creates true geodesic buffers for line and polygon
>   input data. Prior to 10.1, only input point features would create
>   geodesic buffers.